# how to load more then one image in Bitmap (Flex)

Tags: apache-flex, bitmap

i can't download more then one image from url

```
function processXML(e:ResultEvent):void 
    {
        myXML = e.result as XML;
        for (var i:Number=0;i<myXML.icon.length();i++)//amout of urls.Now there tree elements
           {
              loader.load( new URLRequest(myXML.image[i].imageURL.toString()));   //get url             
           }
    }
```

there is event.COMPLETE function

```
private function handleLoadComplete( e:Event ):void

           {


              var bmp:Bitmap = ( e.target as LoaderInfo ).content as Bitmap;
           imgColl.addItem(bmp); //sore elements
           Alert.show("load complete");//scheck for loadin
           img.source = imgColl.getItemAt(1) as Bitmap; // ERROR Store only one element
```

MXML file

```
<mx:Image id="img" width="20" height="20"/>
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use separate loaders for each concurrent request.

It's not explicitly clear from the docs, but it does say this:

> The Loader class overrides the following methods that it inherits, because a Loader object can only have one child display object—the display object that it loads. Calling the following methods throws an exception: addChild(), addChildAt(), removeChild(), removeChildAt(), and setChildIndex(). To remove a loaded display object, you must remove the Loader object from its parent DisplayObjectContainer child array.